# Can anyone offer advice on MUTILPLE codes all seeming to deal with my transmission

Tags: ford, transmission, troubleshooting, obd

2001 Ford Taurus Wagon with 124K miles Duratec engine

Drive car yesterday and everything seemed fine. Came home and parked it like always.

Today the car runs but both the check engine light and the check transmission light (Gear with ! inside) came on upon starting the car. Car will not move. If I was still driving a stick, I swear it sounds like trying to move from a dead stop with a car in like 3rd gear.

I ran a diag scanner just to see what code was active and it spit at a list ---
P1747, P0750, P0760, P1451, P0135, P0141, P0155, P0161, and P0755

At seems like anything electric with deals with the transmission suddenly has an error.

Has anyone even run into something like this? Is it trying to say multiple parts of the transmission suddenly failed, or is it possible the computer has just gone bad?

Any help, advice, or past experiences would be great. Probably will have to towed to a shop either way, but I am just trying to gain a little understand before I take it in

Comment: Put a fully charged good battery on, clear all the codes then re-test. See what comes back.

Comment: As @Solar Mike stated a very common cause for multiple codes is low voltage. The battery would be the first point to check. If that checks out you may have damaged wiring or even a disconnected connector?

Comment: Not the same specifics, but I had a sudden flock of codes on my Cobalt, which turned out to be a bad ground lug, where multiple sensors, etc were crimped together.

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that a connector that contains wiring for both the emission system and transmission are shorting out probably due to corrosion. I remember on the f-150s there was a connector near the fuse panel on the floor behind a removable panel underneath the glove box that would fail. If you could get a wiring schematic that relates to a connector housing containing both of those circuits it's definitely a clue. I would also recommend this Bluetooth scanner "Autel AP200M OBD2 Scanner Bluetooth" for finding more detailed information and very important that it's the AP200M.